# Use postgres constants with pg_prepare/pg_execute

Tags: php, postgresql, constants, prepared-statement

Supposing this table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE log
(
  user smallint NOT NULL,
  moment timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT (clock_timestamp())::timestamp without time zone,
  details text NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT log_pk PRIMARY KEY (user, moment)
);
```

To add a record to the table, I would use the following code:

```php
<?php

  $dbconn = pg_connect('dbname=system');

  $query = <<<EOQ
INSERT INTO
  log
VALUES
  (
    $1,
    DEFAULT,
    $3
  )
EOQ;

// ...
```

With the 'DEFAULT' constant as the second parameter, but for a "collection of bizarre reasons" I need to be able to run it like this:

```php
<?php

  $dbconn = pg_connect('dbname=system');

  $query = <<<EOQ
INSERT INTO
  log
VALUES
  (
    $1,
    $2,
    $3
  )
EOQ;

  $result = pg_prepare($dbconn, '', $query);

  $data=
    [
      10,
      'DEFAULT',
      'IP: 127.0.0.1'
    ];

  $result = pg_execute($dbconn, '', $data);
```

The problem is that, in this way, the constant is received as text and php raise the error '*PHP Warning: pg_execute(): Query failed: ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "DEFAULT"*'.

Is there any way to use postgres constants as parameters with pg_prepare/pg_execute?

PS: I'm using php 8 and postgres 13.4

**EDIT:**

I also tried using this format:

```php
// ...

  $query = <<<EOQ
INSERT INTO
  acessos
VALUES
  (
    $1,
    CASE WHEN $2='DEFAULT' THEN
      DEFAULT
    ELSE
      $2
    END,
    $3
  )
EOQ;

// ...
```

but I got another error message, '*PHP Warning:  pg_prepare(): Query failed: ERROR:  DEFAULT is not allowed in this context*'...

Comment: Unrelated but the use of old style php_pgsql extension shall be discouraged in favour of vastly superior PDO.

Comment: Specify the column names: `insert into log(user, detail) VALUES(42, 'some details');` Also note that columns are unordered in SQL, just like rows.

Answer (score 0):

A "collection of bizarre reasons" calls for a bizarre solution. If you *have* to supply 3 parameters but only use 2 then I suggest to change the query so that it will silently ignore the second one.

```sql
$query = <<<EOQ
INSERT INTO log
VALUES
(
 case when $2 is null or $2 is not null then $1 end, -- const.true but $2 is 'used'
 DEFAULT,
 $3
)
EOQ;
```

or, better, use the default expression explicitly

```sql
$query = <<<EOQ
INSERT INTO
  acessos
VALUES
  (
    $1,
    CASE WHEN $2 ~* '^DEFAULT$' THEN clock_timestamp() ELSE $2::timestamp END,
    $3
  )
EOQ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`DEFAULT` is an SQL keyword, so part of the SQL statement, and you cannot use a parameter for it.  You'll have to use two different `INSERT` statements in your PHP code, one that inserts `moment`, and one that doesn't.

The alternative is to use dynamic SQL, but I think that would be less readable and more complicated (and you have to be careful to avoid SQL injection).